# Chrome packaged app with a Java applet

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is it possible for a Chrome packaged app to contain a Java applet?

I'm attempting to integrate QZ-Print / jZebra into a packaged app, however the applet does not appear and JavaScript receives an error of applet / can't read method of undefined when attempting to call a function.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use any (NPAPI) plugin in a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps).

The documentation lists several [Disabled Web Features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated). Flash and Non-sandboxed plugins are both listed, so they cannot be embedded in a Chrome app. Flash -as a (sandboxed) PPAPI plugin- could be embedded inside a [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), but Java is a non-sandboxed NPAPI plugin, so [it cannot be used in a `<webview>` tag](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-apps/ldoXf5AsqHU/8dMCWUcCMqwJ).

---

And you cannot use Java applets within a legacy [packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps) either, because [Java does not support Chrome extensions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30258). You might have more luck if you try to embed the Java applet from a http(s) site.

Note that both Java applets and legacy packaged apps are deprecated and going to be removed from Chrome in the future ([announcement for Java plugins](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html), [announcement for packaged apps](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html)), so you should try to look for alternatives such as [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging).

Comment: As the term "packaged apps" is often misused to refer to a Chrome Apps, it should be made clear that it is legacy packaged apps that will go away. Chrome Apps are here to stay.

Comment: @MarcRochkind Until packaged apps were available, they were called chrome apps. I've attempted to highlight the difference between the two by turning the terms "chrome app" and "packaged app" in a link, and divide the two sections of my answer by a horizontal line.

Comment: Rob: I just didn't want someone to misinterpret "packaged apps are deprecated."

Comment: All makes sense thanks for that. I've looked into native messaging within Chrome, however I can not get it to communicate with an .exe file. It's as if Chrome is failing to recognise there are native messaging definitions within the registry. Does anyone know if there are any other documentation? The Google documentation is quite basic in terms of explaining functionality and outcomes.

Comment: @ab92014 I suggest to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

It will be an ad-hoc solution, but you can set "always allow" manually in  `chrome://plugins`

Comment: Incorrect, "disabled web features" section from RobW's answer still applies.

Comment: I've tested with a development (unpackaged) app and it works. If it is different in the release package, I haven't tried it...

Comment: Are you sure you refer to Java?

Comment: Double checked now.   `<applet
    code="x.class"
    codebase="."
    alt="..."
    width='100%'
    height='250'>
<p>...</p>
</applet>` works like a charm. Either we are talking about different Java's or Chrome has a security issue (40.0.2214.94 m).

Comment: It also works as a packaged app. "always allow" overrides other restrictions I guess...